# Variable that's being passed with an empty string and causing an undefined index issue in my logs

Tags: php, string, isset, undefined-index

I know this is quite a common question but hopefully someone can provide some help for me.

```php
/**

 * @param $optionid

 * @return mixed

 */

public function getAttributeSwatchHashcode($optionid) {
    $hashcodeData = $this->swatchHelper>getSwatchesByOptionsId([$optionid]);

    return $hashcodeData[$optionid]['value'];
}
```

It looks like `$optionid` has been passed with an empty string. So I believe I need to trace it back to `getAttributeSwatchHashcode()` and figure out why it's being called with no Option ID.

This is where I get a bit confused. I located it in another file.

```html
<div class="icon" style="background-color:<?= $_helper44->getAttributeSwatchHashcode($bgColor) ?>"></div>
```

From what I've been reading adding a check `isset($array[$index])` would be a quick fix? I'm not sure if that works in this case. Do I need to trace it back more or would that be a quick fix to get the logs to stop firing off so much?

Not sure how to include this isset condition or if it's the right place.

Comment: An empty string is a red herring. Inside of that function you are calling another function that hopefully returns an array, but you aren’t checking that, which might be okay. But then you are blindly assuming that something in that array exists. It is the same as this: https://3v4l.org/Pq1I6

Comment: Okay, It makes a bit more sense now. @ChrisHaas I should be looking at $_helper44?

Comment: Unless you have guards in place, you shouldn’t make any assumptions about code in general. As it relates to functions, if you think a function should always return an array, declare that as the return type and PHP will take care of exploding if that ever isn’t true. I can’t tell you where you should be looking, unfortunately, just in general. I _can_ tell you the having a function that accepts a parameter and passes it to another function as an array _feels_ wrong, but might be totally legit.

Comment: I declared the return type as an array. @ChrisHaas